# Merge a data frame and list based on the names of the items in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, merge

Is there a way to merge a data frame and list in R based on the names of the items in a list?

Example want to merge this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Into a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Example of data.frame

```
data = structure(list(Col.A = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), Col.B = c("x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), 
    Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
    "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", 
    "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3"), Variable = c("V1", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V1", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Example list:

```
List = list(GROUP1 = list(V1 = 0.857138, V2 = 1, V3 = 0.5, 
                          V4 = "not limiting", V5 = 0.1), 
            Group2 = list(V1 = 0.65, V2 = 1, V3 = 1, 
                          V4 = 0.6, V5 = 0.25), 
            Group3 = list(V1 = 0.65, V2 = 0.75, V3 = 0.3, 
                          V4 = 1, V5 = 1))
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? `cbind(data,New.var.name = unlist(List))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

names(List) <- stringr::str_to_sentence(names(List))

List |> 
  unlist() |> 
  enframe() |> 
  separate_wider_delim(cols = name, names = c("Group", "Variable"), delim = ".") |> 
  right_join(data)

   Group  Variable value        Col.A Col.B
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>
 1 Group1 V1       0.857138     x     x    
 2 Group1 V2       1            x     x    
 3 Group1 V3       0.5          x     x    
 4 Group1 V4       not limiting x     x    
 5 Group1 V5       0.1          x     x    
 6 Group2 V1       0.65         x     x    
 7 Group2 V2       1            x     x    
 8 Group2 V3       1            x     x    
 9 Group2 V4       0.6          x     x    
10 Group2 V5       0.25         x     x    
11 Group3 V1       0.65         x     x    
12 Group3 V2       0.75         x     x    
13 Group3 V3       0.3          x     x    
14 Group3 V4       1            x     x    
15 Group3 V5       1            x     x
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R use:

```
a <- data.frame(array2DF(structure(List, dim = length(List))), row.names = 'Var1')
data$Col.E <- a[as.matrix(data[c('Group', 'Variable')])]
data

   Col.A Col.B  Group Variable        Col.E
1      x     x Group1       V1     0.857138
2      x     x Group1       V2            1
3      x     x Group1       V3          0.5
4      x     x Group1       V4 not limiting
5      x     x Group1       V5          0.1
6      x     x Group2       V1         0.65
7      x     x Group2       V2            1
8      x     x Group2       V3            1
9      x     x Group2       V4          0.6
10     x     x Group2       V5         0.25
11     x     x Group3       V1         0.65
12     x     x Group3       V2         0.75
13     x     x Group3       V3          0.3
14     x     x Group3       V4            1
15     x     x Group3       V5            1
```

---

Note that I first had to change the name in `List` to match the names given in `data`. ie change `GROUP1` to `Group1`

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(rrapply)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

rrapply(List, how = "melt") %>% 
  mutate(L1 = str_to_title(L1)) %>% 
  left_join(data, .,  join_by(Group == L1 , Variable == L2))

#>    Col.A Col.B  Group Variable        value
#> 1      x     x Group1       V1     0.857138
#> 2      x     x Group1       V2            1
#> 3      x     x Group1       V3          0.5
#> 4      x     x Group1       V4 not limiting
#> 5      x     x Group1       V5          0.1
#> 6      x     x Group2       V1         0.65
#> 7      x     x Group2       V2            1
#> 8      x     x Group2       V3            1
#> 9      x     x Group2       V4          0.6
#> 10     x     x Group2       V5         0.25
#> 11     x     x Group3       V1         0.65
#> 12     x     x Group3       V2         0.75
#> 13     x     x Group3       V3          0.3
#> 14     x     x Group3       V4            1
#> 15     x     x Group3       V5            1
```